# Logarithmic reduction to another LOGSPACE problem

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

For words of the same length $u = u_1..u_n, v = v_1..v_n$ over an alphabet $A$ let $$u \circ v = u_1v_1...u_nv_n$$

Prove that if $L$ over $A \times A$ in in LOGSPACE then $$L' = \{uv : u \circ v \in L\}$$
is also in LOGSPACE

My solution:
We try to log-reduce $L'$ to $L$. So, I mean when a machine $M_L$ tries to read an input then reducing function $f$ gives another input.

Let $I$ be an input tape, word $w = uv = u_1..u_nv_1..v_n, |w| = 2n$ and $w$ starts at 0th cell.

Now, we define $f$:
$$
      f(i) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        I[i/2] & \text{for } i \ even \\
        I[i/2+n] & \text{for } i \ odd
        \end{array}\right]
  $$

My doubts:

1. Is it ok?
2. I used in $f$ division. Is is possible in $LOGSPACE$?

Comment: Please ask only one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking two questions. I will only answer the one about division. Division can be done in logspace, as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76195/1277), which cites the relevant literature.

However, in your case you are interested in *division by 2*, which is easier than general division. I bet you can show yourself that numbers can be divided by 2 in logspace (assuming that they're represented in binary). This operation is known as *right shift*.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I understand why you answer just one question. However, it is the first time when I am making a such problem, so your answer for the first one will be helpful.

Comment: You can ask it separately, but you will have to explain which part of the answer you are not sure about. We usually don't check answers here.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79962/logarithmic-reduction-to-another-problem